# Shop setup for subscribed members

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

Before I start to build this store on my own, I would like to ask if anyone can provide some guidelines on the following setup.
I am trying to build a store with a member area for subscribed members with an annual renewal.

What is the best way to approach this setup? Is there anything I have to consider or be concerned about? Any warning or solution on plugins that I have to consider...

I have attached an image on how I see it. Please comment if there is anything I miss or you have a suggestion on how to build it.

Thanks in advance -
Nermin

[image]